# How to set two primary key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making my first project in SQL. A database for an hardware store. I need to make more than one relation to other table from a single table (need more than one primary key).

When I try to create two `PRIMARY KEY` it has no error, but when I try to make the connections to other tables, those other tables don't recognize those keys.

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    IDProduct int NOT NULL,
    Part nchar(16) CHECK (Part IN ('CPU', 'CPUCooler', 'Motherboard', 'Storage', 'Memory', 'GraphicCard', 'Case', 'PSU')),
    Quantity tinyint,
    Disponibility bit NOT NULL ,
    Price smallmoney NOT NULl,
    OrderID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Encomenda(IDEncomenda),
    PRIMARY KEY (IDProduct, Part)
)
```

I try to do more tables but it didn't work. I search everywhere and didn't find the solution. I saw my teacher doing it but he don't reply to our class for some time now.

I'm expecting to have two `PRIMARY KEY` inside a table or be able to create a relation with other table.

Comment: A table *cannot* have 2 primary keys. You can have a primary key made up of 2 (or more columns), like you do in your attempt, but you can't have 2 primary keys on the same table. If you need a second foreign key candidate use a `UNIQUE` `CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: Also the above would error due to the incorrect syntax near the keyword `ORDER`.

Comment: I completely forgot about 'Order' I translated my code to EN before posting it here. He got another name in my querry

Comment: A column named `OrderID` does not belong in a table named `Product`. You should have a table for Products, a table for Orders, and a table for OrderDetails, where each row in OrderDetails has an OrderID, ProductID, Price, and Qty.

Comment: Help us help you - share the exact error you're getting

Comment: Please give concrete examples, with actual data, that can be used to both demonstrate your needs and test any solution; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example